# The rails way to maunally submit a remote form with ujs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

### Rails 5.2.0

Lets say I have a form without a submit button, And I want another event, for example after a input was entered, to trigger the submission, but still enjoy all of ujs features.

what's the best practice here, should I call a method like Rails.ajax ?
Or fire event via Rails.fire ? is there any docs related to this issue?

My case is debauncing an input for 1 sec and than submit it.

Comment: But how does the form knows you have entered the input the form? Lets say I have to enter "foo bar". How does it know, you finished inputing after entering "foo"?

Comment: Just triggering the submit event on the form does not work?

Comment: Try to trigger via Rails: `trigger('submit.rails')` or `trigger('click.rails')`

Comment: I'm not asking what works, I'm asking for an official way, without clicking a button...

Comment: I believe your suggestion of `Rails.fire` comes close to being official, only based on the fact that `rails-ujs` is relatively new and `Rails.fire` is an event supplied by that library. [This comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546#issuecomment-313981539) also supports `Rails.fire`. Did you end up finding anything else more official?

Comment: no, didn't find anything, but ended up using Rails.fire, would someone like to add an answer or should I ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is an official answer, but variants on this work well for me:

`onchange: "$(this).closest('form').submit();"`

`onchange`, `onblur`, `onclick`. Obviously, that's a jquery solution. But the concept should be clear.